# Joining 3 tables, not getting desired result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have three tables in MySql:
**Events**, **Users** both having many to many relation. Hence, third table **Attend**.

Table content:

**Events**: 
e_id, e_content

**Users** 
u_id, u_details

**Attend** 
e_id, u_id, attending

let consider I am logged in and my uid is 1005.
So I want to see all events whether or not I am attanding the evnet but if I am attending the **Attend.attending** column should be yes else it should be null

I have tried a lot with joins but I have not received the desired query.

like:

```
select e.e_id,u.u_details,a.attending
from Events e 
left join attend a on e.e_id = a.e_id
left join users u on u.u_id = a.U_id
and u.u_id = 1005;
```

with the above query I get same result for all uid

Comment: What you had tried for same??

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` here like

```
select e.e_id,u.u_details,a.attending
from Events e 
left join attend a on e.e_id = a.e_id
left join users u on u.u_id = a.U_id
and u.u_id = 1005;
```

Comment: This wont give all the events it will ignore null uid

Comment: @xQbert, No wonder ... this happens a lot in SO :) only strange this is that ... no reason for downvoting has been provided

Comment: @Siyual it will give events with uid 1005. I want that as well as null

Comment: This query should return all events and have the value of a.attending for user 1005 (if present).  the left joins ensure all events are returned and the "AND" on the last left join ensures only user 1005 is returned.  And since the and is on the join, not the where, the events for which user 1005 isn't involved will still be returned.

Comment: @ArnoldParge Did you try running the query...?

Comment: @ArnoldParge No you can't check for null that way.  Rahul's approach is the correct method.

Comment: @ArnoldParge, query posted in answer is per your post description ... notice am doing a outer join and thus you will get the nulls as well

Comment: @ArnoldParge No, it's not a good idea.  `Null` can never be equal to anything.

Comment: Read up on joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Got it my mistake was only that I was trying **where** clause instead of just **and**. Thanks all, specially @Rahul

Comment: after testing I realised, with this I get same result for all uid. So I have not yet got the solution.

Comment: @ArnoldParge, great ... have no idea. post sample output and desired result

Answer (score 1):

If, as is specifically asked, all events require displaying, but just where a particular user (1005) is attending has attending = "Yes" then is requires a little more than left joins, as if multiple users are attending, it will still display "Yes" for all users attending, even though the u_id is not displayed.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed738/3/1

Shows the query with 2 left joins, and then the 2nd result set which gets what I believe is the required result.

```
select e.e_id,a.u_details,a.attending
from Events e 
left join (select a.*, u.u_details 
                     from attend a 
                     INNER join users u ON
                     (a.u_id = u.u_id and u.u_details = 'will')) a on e.e_id = a.e_id
```

There are more than likely more elegant ways of doing this, but think this does the job.